# Is GDataXML supported by apple

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, xml-parsing

Is GDataXML supported by apple ? I want to write an xml but NSXMLParser do not support writing of xml. So i thought of using third party library GDataXML but will my app be rejected due to this ? I am working on iOS 6. And is there any library which i can use for writing xml without  getting app rejected ? I used [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) and [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) for reference .

Answer (score 1):

On the [GDataXML GitHub page](https://github.com/neonichu/GDataXML), it says this:

> Currently, there is only my very own app Republizierer, which has yet to be submitted to the App Store. At this point in time, I can give you **no guarantees that this library is safe to use** in your iOS applications.

So maybe you should hold off on using it in your app.

Comment: Is GDATAXML supported by iOS 6,

Comment: @Prernachavan - You would be able to use it in your project, but it probably doesn't incorporate modern Objective-C features like ARC, literals, and property declarations because it was last updated a year ago.

Comment: @Prernachavan - Actually, after checking out the code on GitHub, it appears the code does in fact use ARC, just not property declarations and literals.